# When I'm Using ImplicitlyWait my page shows Blank, Why?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium3

When I'm executing my test case if i use the code `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` my execution into my browser show me empty (just white) but if I execute without these codes my test case runs correctly.

[image: This happens with the code ImplicitlyWait]

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Selenium 3.0.1 And Firefox 47.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *version incompatibility problem* - your Firefox browser version is too old for Selenium3. **Update your browser**.

My current setup which works for me:

- selenium 3.4.0
- Firefox 54
- geckodriver 0.17

All currently latest stable.

Comment: what version should have? The lastest version doesn't work with Selenium 3.0.1

Comment: @Blackwidow I have selenium 3.4.0 and Firefox 54 - works for me.